# Doubt on sending audio from Addictive Drums to an Aux track

Tags: vst

In Addictive Drums there are volume faders, and I'd like to know what happens with those faders when you send the audio out. Does the volume on the aux track keep the fader changes?

Answer (score 1):

I'm unfamiliar with Addictive Drums specifically, but it sounds like you are talking about **pre/post-fader send**.

Usually, when you send audio to an aux track, there will be a button somewhere (usually with "pre" on it) which allows you to send the signal **pre-fader**.

- **pre-fader** will 'tap' the signal before it reaches the fader, i.e. the fader changes ***will not*** affect the 'sent' signal.
- **post-fader** will 'tap' the signal after the fader, i.e. the fader changes ***will*** affect the 'sent' signal.

So... in Addictive Drums, when a signal is sent to an aux track, is it sent pre-fader or post-fader?

Well, in my experience the default is always **post-fader**, but there should be a button or option somewhere allowing you to choose. So I'd say the volume changes ***are*** affecting the aux signal.

One way to be sure is to change the fader by a noticeable amount while monitoring only the aux signal; if the changes affect the aux signal, then it *is* routed post-fader.